# create string using dataframe values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

dataframe has

segment | percentage_change

segment1 | 25%

segment2 | 30%

segment3 | 40%

I need to create sentence for top 3:

"Segment3 has highest percentage change of 40%"

"Segment2 has 2nd highest percentage change of 30%"

"Segment1 has 3nd highest percentage change of 25%"
"Segment 1 has 5% more change than segment 2"
"Segment 2 has 10% more change than segment 3"

all these sentence will be added as each cell value in a new dataframe.
Thanks for the help !!

Comment: Is your sentence structure is going to be same ?????

Comment: yes I might add some other sentences but the sentence structure would be same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
#converted column with percentage to numeric
df['num'] = df['percentage_change'].str.rstrip('%').astype(float)
#get 3top rows by numeric column
df1 = df.nlargest(3, 'num')
#create difference column converted to strings
df1['diff'] = df1['num'].diff(-1).fillna(0).astype(str).str.replace('\.[0]*','') + '%'
#shifting segment column
df1['diff_seg'] = df1['segment'].shift(-1)
#default index strating by 1
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
df1.index = df1.index + 1
print (df1)
    segment percentage_change   num diff  diff_seg
1  segment3               40%  40.0  10%  segment2
2  segment2               30%  30.0   5%  segment1
3  segment1               25%  25.0   0%       NaN
```

Then is used `f-string`s for formating of new columns:

```
f1 = lambda x: f'{x["segment"].title()} has {x.name}. highest percentage change of {x["percentage_change"]}'
f2 = lambda x: f'{x["diff_seg"].title()} has {x["diff"]} more change than {x["segment"]}'
df1['out'] = df1.apply(f1, axis=1)
df1['out1'] = df1.iloc[:-1].apply(f2, axis=1)
print (df1)
    segment percentage_change   num diff  diff_seg  \
1  segment3               40%  40.0  10%  segment2   
2  segment2               30%  30.0   5%  segment1   
3  segment1               25%  25.0   0%       NaN   

                                                out  \
1  Segment3 has 1. highest percentage change of 40%   
2  Segment2 has 2. highest percentage change of 30%   
3  Segment1 has 3. highest percentage change of 25%   

                                         out1  
1  Segment2 has 10% more change than segment3  
2   Segment1 has 5% more change than segment2  
3                                         NaN
```

Comment: sir thanks alot for this help but I need to know how do you put all the strings in the different cells of a new dataframe